# Django testing wastes too much time on test database creating

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing

We are try to cover tests on an old, big project which has more than 500 tables in database, and that waste too much time on database creating(more than 1 hour on my RMBP) and db migrations.

We are using PostgreSQL as the Database, cause some GIS about service needs it, so it's hard to use SQLite to replace it.

What I can do to decrease the time on testing preparation?

Comment: Can you use something like [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create objects for testing and skip the DB entirely?

Comment: @IanAuld factory_boy maybe a good tool to replace, but in my case, the biggest problem is creating db. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [django-nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose) and reuse the database like this:

```
REUSE_DB=1 ./manage.py test
```

Be careful that your tests do not leave any junk in the DB. Have a look at the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose#enabling-database-reuse) for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure, I added this line to settings.py, but still get a lot of SQL out put with parameter `-v 2`. On the other hand, it runs much more faster, so I think the database is not really creating new database.

Comment: BTW, I think `REUSE_DB=1 ./manage.py test` means adding `REUSE_DB=1` to settings.py, and run `./manage.py test` in the shell, right?

Comment: `REUSE_DB` is an environment variable and not a setting. You have to set it in your shell. See [source](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/blob/9ec77df1a695d7b45c96c4731e1c26a2e8d93161/django_nose/runner.py#L411)

Comment: It works. But after I settinged like this, there get a DatabaseError -- 'relation "django_site" does not exist' when nose trying to reset database states. Finally I catched the exception but doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

At some point I ended up creating a transaction management middleware that would intercept transaction calls so that all tests were run in a transaction, and then the transaction was rolled back at the end.

Another alternative is to have a binary database dump that gets loaded at the beginning of each test, and then the database is dropped and recreated between tests. After creating a good database,  use [xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/) to create a dump of it. Then, in a per-test setup function, drop and create the database, then use xtrabackup to load the dump. Since it's a binary dump it'll load fairly quickly.

Comment: How can I use database dump instead? I did not find anything about it.